# Hosting my Django site

Tags: python, django, web-services

Hi I'm looking for some advice I currently own a resseller package with Heart internet as I host a few personal websites. However I'm currently learning Django (The python Framework) and want to be able to host my own server.

I have been setting up virtual servers to play around with. Anyway to have SSH access you have to send in and ask them to open it for you, in the meantime of asking them if it was possible to install Django / set up SSH access i was advised that i can't use Django unless i purchase a Virtual machine even though Python is intalled on the server.

Surley i can install Django onto my server if i have SSH access? Has anyone else has a similair issue? Or can anyone advise me on what to do.. The last thing i was to do is spend more money with them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It sounds like you're describing a shared hosting situation where you have SSH access but the webserver is preconfigured for you.  You cannot practically install and serve Django on that machine, because you will not have access to the Apache or other webserver configuration.  You could theoretically serve Django from a port other than the typical HTTP port, but this would be extremely irregular and your hosting company would not appreciate it.

You can deploy Django on Heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django .  It is free to deploy for extremely low-volume applications or for development; cost scales linearly with capacity above that.

You can also use Google App Engine with a slightly older version of Django.  Either of these options have official support from the respective vendors and so they are much better ideas than trying to work around a restriction set by your hosting provider.

Finally, you could pay for a virtual machine, in which you would have full access to the webserver configuration and could serve anything you like.  Virtual machines are available from any number of companies at a wide range of price points.  You could also develop a Django application without hosting it anywhere but your local machine for starters, and worry about hosting after your application is functional.

Comment: You're always going to be better off with a VPS package. They're no longer as cost-prohibitive as they once were. I pay only ~$12/month for my VPS on RackSpace and it comes with free CDN hosting (though you are charged for bandwidth). It's an investment, that's worth every penny, though.

Comment: I actually really like the Heroku or Google App Engine option; VPSes require maintenance (upgrading packages, configuration, etc) and setting them up is itself a complex technical task that some developers will not be able to do.  Heroku is more or less turnkey, so you can focus on the application.  You can also scale it more easily.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answers really appreciate the feedback.. I know i'm going to have to read a little into the links you have provided. 'Heroku' Is this something I install on my servers on my current hosting package? Or do the host the site for me? Looks like I may have to purchase a VPS then, bit of a shame as the server already has Python installed and that's kind of the reason i set it up! I think I get 25% off VPS packages anyway so i think it works out about £9 a month. Is there a way of installing Django on my current system even if it was inside a virtualenv? Thanks again

Comment: Heroku is a service for hosting applications, similar to how your hosting provider is a service for hosting web sites.  You would have to create an account at Heroku to use it.  If you did so, you could host your application there for free (with minimal usage) or at a reasonable cost (for high usage) without needing your own VPS.  Or, you could pay for a VPS and install Django there, if you have the necessary system administration skills.  Either way, you should install Django on your local machine for development purposes first. You do not need a server until you are ready to deploy your app.

Answer (score 14):

AWS :

- Free tier available
- great support(but for technical help you got to pay)
- can use platform (PAAS) BeanStalk
- can customize architecture in case you get a dedicated instance
- great community of support
- Custom domain
- great documentation
- can SSH
- Most popular

Heroku:(Django)

- Free to some extent
- Can use only POSTgresql in free plan
- git must
- Good support
- easy to start
- custom domain
- Can use bash in production(Not SSH).. cannot make direct changes in production. This is what makes your App stable. Any change/update goes through git.
- code maintenance - good (deployment through git heroku commands only)
- use AWS S3 to store static files
- Temporary files are removed perodically
- Once you scale that they start to bill, it is really costly.
- Since this is a PAAS, you have got what you have got. It takes lots of efforts to customize(to some extent) the architecture of the APP.

Google App Engine:( Flask/Django project.)

- Free to some extent
- very easy to start(hello world app)
- custom domain
- code maintenance - good (automatic deployment)
- Support is not available

Pythonanywhere:

- Free to some extent
- No custom domain in free plan
- easy to use
- Good support

Webfaction:(Django)

- Not free.. (I think (minimal plan) costs 10 $ per month on shared hosting. )
- SSH available
- custom domain
- Architecture customization.
- Good support

Answer (score 8):

I have really good experiences with [pythonanywhere.com](http://pythonanywhere.com). It's also free for really small projects.

For me it seems to be just perfect for experimenting with django. Here is a short story how I switched from Google App Engine to pythonanywhere.com: [Django unchained - python in the cloud](http://freeconnection.blogspot.hu/2013/08/python-django-unchained.html)

Answer (score 3):

I was doing the virtual server thing for a while - then entered Heroku. An extremely easy (and in some cases completely free) way to deploy my django application.

I started where you are,in a shared hosting environment trying to make django work. I then taught myself a lot of server admin and server setup things - thereby moving to a dedicated virtual server setup.

Alas making Django work with apache and on a Centos box can be a pain - But Heroku made it all better. Easy app deployment and scalability. Heroku is a cloud application deployment service - it's all the benefits of a virtual server without the setup. It doesn't actually install on your server

Check out these two articles

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django

http://rdegges.com/devops-django-part-4-choosing-heroku  (There are some more to this article but they are very lengthy)

I had a new django app up on the internet in half the time. There is lots of cost estimations involved, which is why I would dive deep into the second article and it's various parts.

Answer (score 2):

You can host Django on Amazon EC2. If you take advantage of their [free tier](http://aws.amazon.com/free/) you can do so free for one year in a micro instance (618Mb RAM, 30Gb filesystem). You get full control of the machine, including SSH access. There are a number of freely available images that already bundle Django including the [BitNami Django Amazon Machine Image](http://bitnami.org/stack/djangostack#cloudImage) which is also available for free  (disclaimer: I am one of the BitNami developers)